# Automapper ITypeConverter error after package update

Tags: c#, automapper

I updated Automapper package on an relatively old project. And I'm having troubles understanding what's needed to be changed in this class (or if the problem resides elsewhere).

I'm getting:

"'ResolutionContext' does not contain a definition of SourceValue and no extension method..."

```
public class PagedListConverter<T1, T2> : ITypeConverter<IPagedList<T1>, IPagedList<T2>>
{
    public IPagedList<T2> Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var models = (StaticPagedList<T1>)context.SourceValue;  // Error 
        var viewModels = models.Select(Mapper.Map<T1, T2>);

        return new StaticPagedList<T2>(viewModels, models.PageNumber,
                       models.PageSize, models.TotalItemCount);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They changed `ITypeConverter`. So you need to change your code like it:

```
public class PagedListConverter<T1, T2> : ITypeConverter<IPagedList<T1>, IPagedList<T2>>
{
    public IPagedList<T2> Convert(
    IPagedList<T1> source, 
    IPagedList<T2> destination, 
    ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var models = (StaticPagedList<T1>)source; 
        var viewModels = models.Select(Mapper.Map<T1, T2>);

        return new StaticPagedList<T2>(
            viewModels, 
            models.PageNumber,
            models.PageSize, 
            models.TotalItemCount);
    }
}
```